# Python executable with pyinstaller does nothing

Tags: python, google-sheets, python-3.6, pyinstaller

I have a script in python to update some cells on google sheets. If i run it on visual studio code it works perfectly but i want to do an exe to opten in an automaticly run the script for and easy use of it. The problem is that i did the exe with pyinstaller. I opened it and the file opens like 1 second it close again and nothings happens on the google sheets. What can be the problem?

this is the code of the script

```
from smart_sensor_client.smart_sensor_client import SmartSensorClient
import json
import requests
import pkg_resources.py2_warn
DEFAULT_SETTINGS_FILE = 'settings.yaml'
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.\
    from_json_keyfile_name('Smartsensors-02d98c39eaac.json',scope)
client=gspread.authorize(credentials)
sheet = client.open('tutorial1').sheet1


def run_task(settings_file=DEFAULT_SETTINGS_FILE) -> bool:

    # Create the client instance
    client = SmartSensorClient(settings_file=settings_file)

    # Authenticate
    if not client.authenticate():
        print('Authentication FAILED')
        return False

    # Get list of plants
    plants = client.get_plant_list()

    # Iterate the plant list and print all assets therein
    for plant in plants:

        # Get list of assets
        response = client.get_asset_list(organization_id=client.organization_id)
        if len(response) == 0:
            print('No assets in this plant')  
        else:

            nombre=[]
            for asset in response:
                nombre.append(asset['assetName'])
            lastsynctime=[]
            for asset in response:
                lastsynctime.append(asset['lastSyncTimeStamp'])
            sensorid=[]
            for asset in response:
                sensorid.append(asset['sensorIdentifier'])
            tiposubscripcion=[]
            for asset in response:
                asset_data = client.asset_get_asset_by_id(asset_id=asset['assetID'])
                tiposubscripcion=[].append(asset_data['sensor']['subscription']['subscriptionLevel']['description'])
            finsubscripcion=[]
            for asset in response:
                asset_data = client.asset_get_asset_by_id(asset_id=asset['assetID'])
                finsubscripcion.append(asset_data['sensor']['subscription']['endDate'])
            info=[nombre,sensorid,lastsynctime,tiposubscripcion,finsubscripcion]
            sheet.update('A1', info)

    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':

    result = run_task()

    if result is True:
        print('Task SUCCESS')
    else:
        print('Task FAILED')
```

Comment: have you tried opening the exe from the terminal? so you can see the output and exceptions in case any happen?

Comment: Yes. Nothing happens again. It opens and close fast

Comment: And it doesn't print anything either? Well you've really not provided any screenshots or any information whatsoever, so how are we supposed to help? Could you atleast post the code itself

Comment: sorry i will post the code.

Comment: You should probably use logs, and read the output in the terminal or write it to a file to check whats going on. Or it could be a problem with your .exe build.